# I am trying to print some corresponding values to a character but condition always going to else

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am trying to print some values specified in if condition but compiler throws errors that this variable is not declared in this scope.

````
```

#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char i, p, P, z, Z, e, E, d, D;
  cin>>i;

  if(i==p || i==P)
    cout<<"PrepBytes";

  else if(i==z || i==Z)
    cout<<"Zenith";

  else if(i==e || i==E)
    cout<<"Expert Coder";

  else if(i==d || i==D)
    cout<<"Data Structure";

  else
    cout<<"Wrong Input";

  return 0;
}
````

```
Output:-

PS E:\C++> .\a.exe
d
Wrong Input
```

Comment: Where is the compiler output?

Comment: @Amit Mittal These variables char i, p, P, z, Z, e, E, d, D; are not initialized and have indeterminate values. As result the program has undefined behavior.

Comment: Make up your mind: Is it a compiler error, or do you get the wrong output when running it?

Comment: it's not a compiler error it is showing the wrong output.

Comment: You should get lots of warnings about use of uninitialized variables. If you don't, make sure you turn on compiler warnings e.g. `-Wall` for GCC.

Answer (score 4):

You're comparing your `i` with uninitialized values `p, P, etc...`.

Did you want to compare the input character with the characters `'p', 'P'...`?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  char i;
  cin>>i;

  if(i=='p' || i=='P')
    cout<<"PrepBytes";

  else if(i=='z' || i=='Z')
    cout<<"Zenith";

  else if(i=='e' || i=='E')
    cout<<"Expert Coder";

  else if(i=='d' || i=='D')
    cout<<"Data Structure";

  else
    cout<<"Wrong Input";

  return 0;
}
```

Live example [here](https://ideone.com/EwHypQ).

Answer (score 0):

If be honestly, it's not the "Wrong Input". In your program the "else" - condition says that the "i" doesn't equal to any variable (i, p, P etc.). You shall to initialize all of these variables. Or use such condition:

```
if (i == 'p' || i == 'P')
```

And so on.